# Having trouble with Boolean and fancy fonts

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to use the Boolean modifier to etch out (difference) words into an object. I've have converted the font into a mesh. If I use a simple font, there is no issue. But when I try to use a fancy cursive style font, it makes the object I'm trying to etch disappear or just doesn't do anything. I've even tried using a simple square object to etch out, same result. So I'm sure it's not the object, but the fancy font. And unfortunately, the customer's logo uses a fancy font.

Comment: What blender version do you use? Please provide scrinshot and blender file. You can use this link: https://blend-exchange.com/ for uploading blender file. Also, probably, it will be helpfull in your case if you provide a link to the font, or give a name of the font.

Comment: In general boolean operations oftenly give incorrect result, espetually if you try to boolean objects of dificult shape. Universal solution is to avoid boolean if it don't give good result at first try. Instead of boolean you can use modeling - it will take more time but topology always will be better. Also if you try to substract or union text with some surface, probably it will be better to extrude this text using displacement.

Comment: maybe try Knife Project?

Comment: remesh your font object before use boolean